# Sum all values in all rows using array formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I would like an array formula to sum up columns G26:AD per row, since the amount of rows is dynamic.

```
=ArrayFormula(sum(G26:26))
```

does not work. I tried using MMULT but did not manage to get it working:

```
=MMULT(G26:26,TRANSPOSE(ARRAYFORMULA(COLUMN(G26:26)^0)))
```

Any other ideas?

Comment: Are you looking to place the sum of each row in a cell in that row, meaning sum the contents of G2:2 and place the answer in cell F2 and the sum G3:3 and place that in F3, etc?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Sum by rows

The sum of each row in `A:C`:

`=arrayformula(mmult(A2:C*1, transpose(A2:C2 * 0 + 1)))`

[image]

**Edit.** This one is even shorter: `=arrayformula(mmult(A2:C*1, transpose(A2:C2 ^ 0)))`

---

## Sum by rows with conditions

`=arrayformula(mmult(A2:C*--(A2:C>0), transpose(A2:C2 ^ 0)))`

[image]

Other conditions:

`=arrayformula(mmult(A2:D*1, transpose(A2:D2 ^ 0*iseven(column(A2:D2)))))`

[image]

Comment: You sir, are a genius!

Comment: If you know in advance how many columns you have you can also do `=mmult(A2:C10, {1;1;1})`. This example also highlights the rather vague `transpose(A2:C2 * 0 + 1)`. All this needs to do is produce a column of `1` values.

Answer (score 4):

now possible with just:

```
=BYROW(G26:AD; LAMBDA(x; SUM(x)))
```

Comment: This is awesome! Is there a better way to avoid "0" output than this?
=BYROW(G26:AD, LAMBDA(x, IF(SUM(x)>0,SUM(x),"")))

Comment: @Joesy_Mosk try: `=BYROW(G26:AD; LAMBDA(x; IFERROR(1/(1/SUM(x)))`